# SNS publish to topic with phone number is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, boto3, amazon-sns

I have boto3 code that creates a topic and creates a subscription to that topic and publishes the message to the topic.

The code was working fine. I tried to add a US number to the mix of Indian phone number subscribed group and everything went south. I don't get any errors all the responses are successful but I don't receive any messages.

Then I tried with normal console publish a message, even the console publish is not working.

TO cross-verify it the issue was with the region I tried publishing in us-east-1 and all worked fine.

Here is my code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sns = boto3.client("sns")
    number = ['+91xxxxxxxx','+1xxxxxxxxxxxx','+91xxxxxxxxxx']
    
    response = sns.create_topic(
    Name='loadeo-demo',
    Attributes={
        
    }
    
    )
    arn = response['TopicArn']
    print ("arn: " + arn)
    
    
    for phno in number:
        
        response = sns.subscribe(
        TopicArn=arn,
        Protocol='sms',
        Endpoint=phno,
        Attributes={
            
        },
        ReturnSubscriptionArn=False
        )
    
    # print(response)
    
    response = sns.list_subscriptions_by_topic(
    TopicArn=arn
    
    )
    print (response)
    
    response = sns.publish(
    topicArn=arn,    
    Message="A Load of your interest has been placed.\n" + "Please visit the web for more details.\n" + "Thank you",
        
)
```

Comment: "everything went south" is not very information. What exactly when wrong? Any error messages?

Comment: I don't get any errors. All the logs looks okay 
Https response is also 200. But I don't get any messages

Comment: "I tried publishing in us-east-1 and all worked fine." so why not use this region ?

Comment: User Requirements. 
And I tried only the push message feature there I didn't run the code there

Comment: Not all regions [support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-supported-regions-countries.html) sms. Maybe your are using non-supported region?

Comment: But it was working fine before. I am using us-east-2

Comment: @Marcin the code is not working now in both the regions

Comment: At the moment, I don't know what could be the reason.

Comment: @Marcin something with the code?

Comment: I don't know what was you original code that worked. But the code will try to create same topic for each lambda invocation. Not sure if this is your intention?

Comment: @Marcin This was my original code. 
I just added one more number to the number list. 
Yes it was the intention to do that

Comment: If I add an email address to the topic subscription I am getting an email but no sms

Comment: Apparently, this is an open issue with SNS. 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=244891&start=25&tstart=0